# C# - Show Rich Text String in Editor with Format

Tags: rtf

Using notepad++, I created a rtf file called test2.rtf. In that I have below

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs18 Test Rich Text Note\par
\par
Good News!\par
\par
\bullet  This Test line 1.\par
\bullet  This is test line 2.\par
}
```

When I open test2.rtf in MS WORD it shows fine like below

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to load below UTF-8 rich text format string to QuillJS editor so that it shows in editor with all formatting like bold, bullets, alignment,..

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}}
    \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs18 Test Rich Text Note\par
    \par
    Good News!\par
    \par
    \bullet  This Test line 1.\par
    \bullet  This is test line 2.\par
    }
```

**Solution:**

I used RtfPipe open source library.

https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe

I used it like below

```
public static string ConvertRichTextIntoHTML(string richText)
{
  string html = string.Empty;
  StringReader reader = new StringReader(richText);
  RtfSource rtf = new RtfSource(reader);
  html = Rtf.ToHtml(rtf);
  return html;
}
```

Comment: It seems quillJs doesn't support rtf. 'https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2730'. How did you get arround this?

Comment: I used RtfPipe third party library.